# how to toggle between two css classes view types with react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a List and Grid type display. How do I toggle between them in React. I want to toggle between jsGridView and jsListView classes.

> **This is the vanilla js of the toggling of classes**

```
  const listView = document.querySelector('.list-view');
  const gridView = document.querySelector('.grid-view');
  const projectsList = document.querySelector('.project-boxes');
  
  listView.addEventListener('click', () => {
    gridView.classList.remove('active');
    listView.classList.add('active');
    projectsList.classList.remove('jsGridView');
    projectsList.classList.add('jsListView');
  });
  
  gridView.addEventListener('click', () => {
    gridView.classList.add('active');
    listView.classList.remove('active');
    projectsList.classList.remove('jsListView');
    projectsList.classList.add('jsGridView');
  });
```

> ** this is my react file where I have the display items and buttons to toggle. how do I implement the toggle event listeners into my react file**
> **How do I toggle between the two classes - jsGridVew and jsListView**

```
const [isActive, setIsActive] = useState(false)

    const listToggle = () => {
     setIsActive(!isActive)
    }

   <button key={isActive} className="view-btn list-view" title="List View" onClick={listToggle}>
        <i className="fal fa-list-ul fa-2x"></i>
    </button>

    <button className="view-btn grid-view active" title="Grid View">
        <i className="fal fa-th-large fa-2x"></i>
     </button>

     <div className="project-boxes jsGridView">
        {!loading && records.length === 0 ? (<h4 style={{ margin: '20px' }} className='center'>No 
           records, sorry</h4>) : records.map((record, key) => (
             <RecordItem key={key} record={record} isFilter={isFilter} filterByWhat={filterByWhat} />
           ))}
      </div>
```

EDIT: > **I also want to add an 'active class on each button on click. I've tried somethings but it doesn't work**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming this div is where you want to toggle between `jsGridView` and `jsListView`

```
<div className="project-boxes jsGridView">
```

So why not use a state variable to store the class name? Then use the `onClick` even to set it.

```
const [cName, setClassName] = useState('jsGridView');

return (
<Fragment>
   <button className="view-btn list-view" title="List View" onClick={() => setClassName('jsListView')}>
        List View
    </button>
   <button className="view-btn list-view" title="Grid View" onClick={() => setClassName('jsGridView')}>
        Grid View
     </button>


     <div className={"project-boxes "+cName}>
        {!loading && records.length === 0 ? (<h4 style={{ margin: '20px' }} className='center'>No 
           records, sorry</h4>) : records.map((record, key) => (
             <RecordItem key={key} record={record} isFilter={isFilter} filterByWhat={filterByWhat} />
           ))}
      </div>
</Fragment>
)
```

So here you set your class to `jsGridView` initially so it renders in grid view by default. But you also have 2 buttons that can flip it between grid and list view.

You can also add an active class to the button if you want.

```
   <button className={"view-btn list-view"+(cName === 'jsListView' ? ' active_btn':'')} title="List View" onClick={() => setClassName('jsListView')}>
        List View
    </button>
   <button className={"view-btn list-view"+(cName === 'jsGridView' ? ' active_btn':'')} title="Grid View" onClick={() => setClassName('jsGridView')}>
        Grid View
     </button>
```

Answer (score 0):

If one class is on, and the other is off, you can do

```
function toggleClass(elem) {
  const classList = elem.classList;
  classList.toggle('class1');
  classList.toggle('class2');
}
```

Now the on/off status of the two classes is reversed

Also, in your Styles / CSS file, you can add :not on one class and then not need to use the other class, like

```
#elem.class1 {
  color: ...;
  font-size: ...;
}

#elem.class2, #elem:not(.class1) {
  color: ...;
  font-size: ...;
}
```

So that :not(.class1) has the same styling effects as adding class2

Answer (score 0):

In React, it's uncommon to mix "vanilla" imperative JS and React like this. React provides a clean solution for toggling displayed elements that I would advise you use instead.

Take the following as an example:

```js
// list-view.jsx
const ListView = ({ items=[] }) => {

  const itemsElements = items.map(item => {
    return (<li>{item}</li>)
  });
  
  return (<ul>{itemsElements}</ul>)
}

// grid-view.jsx
const GridView = ({ items=[] }) => {

  const itemsElements = items.map(item => {
    return (<span>{item} </span>)
  });
  
  return (<div>{itemsElements}</div>)
}

// list-grid-view.jsx
const ListGridView = ({ items=[] }) => {
  const [listView, setListView] = React.useState(true);
  
  // this fn toggles the listView variable
  const toggleListView = React.useCallback(() => {
    setListView(!listView);
  }, [listView, setListView]);
  
  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={toggleListView} >Toggle!</button>
      {listView ? <ListView items={items} /> : <GridView items={items} />}
    </div>
  );
}

const items = ['Hello', 'World', '!'];
const element = <ListGridView items={items} />

ReactDOM.render(element, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```